# how to remove the error label for project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have one java web project in eclipse EE and it has error label hint, but I check the project build path and all folders in projects.There is no any issues.

What's more, I tried : clean the project and build again, but it still hint error label.

So how to found the root cause and solve the question?

[image]

Comment: `CTRL` + `3` then type `markers`, find the problem and see if there is a quick fix.

Comment: @BroSlow, I had tried it but still can't remove.

Comment: @KevinBowersox your comment is very good for answer, I solve my question and many thanks to you.You can post the comment as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse does this sometimes, I don't know why. First, check if there's an error being reported; perhaps you missed it. Check in the Problems tab (Window -> Show View -> Problems if it's not visible).

If you truly have no issues left, try refreshing (right-click on project -> Refresh) then cleaning the project (Project -> Clean...).

If that doesn't work, close all editor windows, then close and reopen the project (right-click on project -> Close Project). You might have to restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>** then type `markers`, find the problem in the markers list and see if there is a `Quick Fix`.